# How to make a customize arrow with React-xarrows?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xarrows

I use React-xarrows library in my project. What I need is to make an arrow like in this example: https://resources.jointjs.com/tutorial/html-elements I cannot use JointJS, only xarrow is avaliable. Looked for examples, but it didn't help.

This is a part of my code with an arrow (props I use). How can I make a changable arrow with this library?

```
 start={link.sourceTableName}
            end={link.targetTableName}
            path={"straight"} 
            headShape={"arrow1"}
            headSize={12}
            color={area.color}
            zIndex={arrowIsShawn}
            strokeWidth={arrowWidth}            
            key={link.name}            
            passProps={{
                onClick: (event) => onDeleteArrowHandler(link.name),
```